# How does the length of the output of a problem inform its complexity?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, decision-problem

Consider the **decision** problem: [Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). For an input set of integers, it asks for a **Yes/No answer** to the question of whether or not we can find a subset of elements of this input that add up to 0. The output for this problem is $O(1)$ and simple (e.g. 1/0). This problem is **NP-Complete**, which as far as I understand is only defined for **decision problems**.

Now consider a problem associated with Subset sum that asks to **output** all **such subsets** that add up to 0.  As far as I understand, this is an **optimization problem**.

Moreover, the **output** of this problem **could grow** as $O(2^N)$ if $N$ is the size of the input array (i.e. the output grows as fast as the cardinality of the power set of the input).  If so, what does this say about the **complexity** or **complexity class** of this optimization problem?

More generally speaking, does the size of the output of an optimization problem provide a necessary lower bound on the complexity of the optimization or associated decision problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not an optimization problem.  It takes at least one step of computation per bit or word of output (depending on the model of computation), so since the output can be $\Omega(2^N)$, that means the worst-case running time will be $\Omega(2^N)$, no matter what algorithm you use.  Thus, the complexity is $\Omega(2^N)$.

Yes, the size of the output is a lower bound on the running time to produce that output.

Comment: Thanks! When you say one step **_per bit_**, I'm curious about this. What computational model would that be for? (does it have an actual name?) I ask because I'm used to the [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) notation which I think the authors call the "RAM model" and which assumes constant-time operations for k-bit-word-sized data (e.g. words can be k=32 bits, or k=64 bits). Would the number of bits per computer word actually change the complexity e.g. in the case you described ("_one step of computation per bit, so you the output can be $Ω(2^)$"_?

Comment: @Josh, in that model, it would be one step per word of output.